# loadPolicyFile doesnt work in AS3

Tags: java, sockets, actionscript, connection

(Im bad in english i try to be good for a good explain)

i got a client socket in AS3 and a server in Java. In localhost, i got no problem to connect my client and my server. They can exchange data with no problem with this line :

```
socket.connect("127.0.0.1", 2030);
```

Its ok, my server can receive a Byte[] data , can read and write to my client with no problem.

But now i want to past the server "online" so i open the port 2030 for the connection and the 82 port, and i try to read the crossdomain.xml to be autorized, with :

```
Security.loadPolicyFile("http://90.20.233.143:82/crossdomain.xml");
socket.connect("http://90.20.233.143", 2030);
```

now when im start the connection ... have got some problem with ***Security.loadPolicyFile***

Im getting  on JAVA Server :

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

And in Client As3 (in french):

> Connexion au serveur.... Vous etes connecté au serveur
>
> Avertissement :La balise  non valide est ignorée
>   pour le domaine 'http://90.20.233.143' dans le fichier de régulation
>   présent à http://90.20.233.143:82/crossdomain.xml
>
> Socket error: [IOErrorEvent type="ioError" bubbles=false
>   cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2031: Erreur de socket.
>   URL: 90.19.160.185"] // its sur cause "connection reset" on JAVA

my code in my crossdomain.xml :

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
    <allow-access-from domain="http://90.20.233.143/" to-ports="*"/>
    <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

i dont know where is the problem ...

Comment: The server that you have listening on port 82, it is a `socket-based policy server` and not an http server? I would start be using Adobe's sample policy server running on the default port 843 to test your client and if it loads the policy and thus can then open a socket to your server's port 2030 for read/write data, then you can setup a production style policy server. Adobe has python and perl examples, make sure it works that one of those first @ http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/socket_policy_files.html

Answer (score 0):

It's a http server , http://90.20.233.143:82/crossdomain.xml , is path of crossdomain.xml.

The client can read the XML but he said that "marker" isnt good, so he will ignore the marker ("balise" in french). SO the plan is open port 843 on my http server ? Or java server ?

Comment: Policy servers are not http based, they are tcp socket based and send the `xml` back as series of bytes to the Flash client, review the Adobe sample policy servers to see how it is handled.

Answer (score 0):

Ok ok so i convert the code in a Byte in XML file , and by the method Security.loadPolicyFile , i read the XML ?